# number of occurrences of every word on page

Tags: php, arrays, full-text-search, counting

I am attempting to count the number of occurrences of every unique word on a page (think SEO 'word count' that you see on woorank etc. - but not for that purpose!)

I am really struggling on how to set this up:-

At the moment I am thinking of reading each word and then checking if it is unique against an array -> if unique add to array with `occurences=>1` - then if I find the same word later just +1.

However this seems really cumbersome and slow for large blocks of text (especially as I will have to strip commas etc, convert all to lower case etc.) -> is there are a better way, has someone got a code snippet or library for this task?

For clarity

The Cat ran away with the hat. The spoon had already run away with another cat, far far away.

Would yield:

`the => 3,
away => 3,
cat => 2,
with => 2,
far => 2,
spoon => 1,
hat => 1,
ran => 1,
run => 1,
had => 1,
another => 1,
already => 1`

Thanks in advance - if there is no better way then that is fine!

ASIDE

I contemplated do a `replace($word,"")` on all words once found and counted -> but this seems just as cumbersome.

Comment: Not ure about how to do it (but that's your work), but you could certainly use functions like `substr_count()` or `str_word_count()` in your code.

Comment: pointers like this always helpful, but yeah - same feeling, not sure how to do it without 'brute force' :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/array_count_values) in conjunction with [`str_word_count()`](http://php.net/str_word_count):

```
$wordCounts = array_count_values(str_word_count(strtolower($sentence), 1));
arsort($wordCounts);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [the] => 3
    [away] => 3
    [cat] => 2
    [far] => 2
    [with] => 2
    [run] => 1
    [another] => 1
    [already] => 1
    [hat] => 1
    [ran] => 1
    [spoon] => 1
    [had] => 1
)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/133271)

Comment: Thank you! - quick question though, should i not sort before doing the count? will that not be quicker?

Comment: plus i presume I will still need to convert to lower case string to ensure `the` `The` etc. are counted together?

Comment: @GrahamRitchie: The sort is completely optional. And no, sorting before doing the count would not work, as `array_count_values` will reorder the items in the array. Also, you can simply convert the whole sentence into lowercase before doing this. See my updated answer (and demo).

Comment: cheers sweety - as I thought but I was being really thick and hadn't though about array_count_values -> so was trying to do it manually :-P +1 and accepted!

Answer (score 0):

Split all the words (you could use a tokenizer like the ones users in Solr to "clean" them), put then in array, sort it, and array unique count. It really would depend on the language, but it will always be faster to use the language native functions that iterate the text by yourself.

In php:

```
$array = preg_split('/[\s,\.]+/', strtolower($text));
$unique = array_count_values($array);
print_r($unique);
```

Comment: thanks for the help but regex is a big no no if I can avoid it - just too slow on massive strings. Cheers for suggestions though.